# Пинг на PHP. Как привязать БД?

Tags: php, база-данных

Имеется код PHP. Как сделать так, чтобы Ip адреса брались из БД и списком выводился у каждого результат пинга?

```html
 <?php
 class CheckDevice {

        public function myOS(){
            if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === (chr(87).chr(73).chr(78)))
                return true;

            return false;
        }

        public function ping($ip_addr){
            if ($this->myOS()){
                if (!exec("ping -n 1 -w 1 ".$ip_addr." 2>NUL > NUL && (echo 0) || (echo 1)"))
                    return true;
            } else {
                if (!exec("ping -q -c1 ".$ip_addr." >/dev/null 2>&1 ; echo $?"))
                    return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }

    $ip_addr = "151.101.193.69";

    if ((new CheckDevice())->ping($ip_addr))
        echo "The device exists";
    else 
        echo "The device is not connected";
        ?>
```

Comment: По запросу `php работа с бд` выводятся сотни мануалов.

Comment: Сотни, но конкретики никакой. С обычным выводом понятно, как работать, но как вкрутить именно в этот код - не ясно. Если я вместо IP поставлю переменную, которая будет получать результаты из БД, работать не будет, если значение не одно.

Comment: Мануалы - не для слепого копирования, а понимания сути работы с базами данных, @ДмитрийБ.

Comment: В том и суть, что написано всё скудным языком и понять это сложно. Информации полно, а объяснения толком и нет. Так же, как и на этих форумах. Никто не объясняет, а лишь критикует. @Daniel Protopopov

Comment: @ДмитрийБ.для объяснения вам нужно общаться с живым человеком, желательно лицом к лицу, задавая вопросы, уточняя и т.д. Как вы наверное заметили, наше сообщество более нацелено на решение технических вопросов, нежели чем общение, через текст. Так что для разъяснений можно только порекомендовать знающего коллегу, либо кого-то ещё, у кого есть время, интерес и знания для растолковывания вам. А критика - она полезна, глядишь и усвоите что-нибудь, если не будете относиться к ней чересчур лично.